# ECDSA signature verification: Go vs OpenSSL

Tags: c++, go, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

I'm trying to verify an ECDSA signature for a hash using a public key. I've written a small Go program that successfully does this but I've been unable to port it to C++.

Here is my input data:

- Public key: `MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEDd9VXmpHjV4voFO+0ZoFPlRr5icZXquxsr9EkaOUO9B7Wl1DAgGI0EKCm1++Bl2Od32xZFeFuG07OTpTMVOCPA==`
- Hash: `562d6ddfb3ceb5abb12d97bc35c4963d249f55b7c75eda618d365492ee98d469`
- Signature: `304502204d6d070117d445f4c2fcdbd4df037a1c8cfee2a166353c2e562cd5efd06e914d022100bb06439ded1478bd19022519dc06a84ba18ea4bf30ea9eb9ea90f8b66dad12c7`

Here is my working go program:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    key_, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEDd9VXmpHjV4voFO+0ZoFPlRr5icZXquxsr9EkaOUO9B7Wl1DAgGI0EKCm1++Bl2Od32xZFeFuG07OTpTMVOCPA==")
    key, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pkey_)
    msg, _ := hex.DecodeString("562d6ddfb3ceb5abb12d97bc35c4963d249f55b7c75eda618d365492ee98d469")
    sig, _ := hex.DecodeString("304502204d6d070117d445f4c2fcdbd4df037a1c8cfee2a166353c2e562cd5efd06e914d022100bb06439ded1478bd19022519dc06a84ba18ea4bf30ea9eb9ea90f8b66dad12c7")

    valid := ecdsa.VerifyASN1(key.(*ecdsa.PublicKey), msg[:], sig)

    if !valid {
      panic("key invalid")
    }
}
```

And here is my broken C++ program that fails at the very last assertion. I'd like to know why that is:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

std::string decode_hex_str(std::string const &hex) {
  std::string str;
  for (std::size_t i { 0 }; i < hex.size(); i += 2) {
    auto byte { hex.substr(i,2) };
    str.push_back(std::strtol(byte.c_str(), nullptr, 16));
  }

  return str;
}

int main() {
  std::string key_ {
R"(
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEDd9VXmpHjV4voFO+0ZoFPlRr5icZXquxsr9EkaOUO9B7Wl1DAgGI0EKCm1++Bl2Od32xZFeFuG07OTpTMVOCPA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
)"
  };

  std::string msg { decode_hex_str("562d6ddfb3ceb5abb12d97bc35c4963d249f55b7c75eda618d365492ee98d469") };
  std::string sig { decode_hex_str("304502204d6d070117d445f4c2fcdbd4df037a1c8cfee2a166353c2e562cd5efd06e914d022100bb06439ded1478bd19022519dc06a84ba18ea4bf30ea9eb9ea90f8b66dad12c7") };

  auto bio { BIO_new_mem_buf(key_.data(), key_.length()) };
  assert(bio);

  auto key { PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) };

  EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx { nullptr };
  EVP_PKEY *pkey { nullptr };

  int status;
  bool verified;

  mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
  assert(mdctx);

  pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
  assert(pkey);

  assert(EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pkey, key) == 1);

  assert(EVP_DigestVerifyInit(mdctx, nullptr, EVP_sha256(), nullptr, pkey) == 1);

  assert(EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(mdctx, msg.data(), msg.length()) == 1);

  status = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(mdctx, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(sig.data()), sig.length());

  switch (status) {
    case 0:
      verified = false;
      break;
    case 1:
      verified = true;
      break;
    default:
      assert(false);
  }

  EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);
  EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

  assert(verified);
}
```

Comment: There's no problem statement in your question—I mean "I have written a program which does not do what I wanted it to" [is not one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please work on improving your question.

Comment: Unlike `VerifyASN1()`, `EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate()` expects the data and not the hash of the data. If you use the data instead of the data hash in the C/C++ code, verification is successful.

Comment: @Topaco Ah that makes sense, but what if I don't have access to the data itself?

Comment: Since a hash is not reversible and therefore the data cannot be reconstructed from the hash, you need a function on the C/C++ side that also expects the hash and not the data, see e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239376).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EVP_DigestVerify{Init/Update/Final}`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestVerifyInit.html) do two things:

- They hash the input data
- Then they verify the computed hash against the signature

[`ecdsa.VerifyASN1`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdsa#VerifyASN1) on the other hand does only the second step from the above, already taking in the hash as input.

The OpenSSL function that does that is [`ECDSA_verify`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ECDSA_verify.html).

So you can do something like:

```
BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key_.data(), key_.length());

EC_KEY* key = PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

int verified = ECDSA_verify(
    0,
    (unsigned char const*)msghash.data(), msghash.length(),
    (unsigned char const*)sig.data(), sig.length(),
    key
);

std::cout << verified << std::endl;
```

Should print `1`.

---

Note that the variable naming in your code is confusing - the variable `msg` actually contains the message *digest*. So `msghash` or `digest` would be a better name for it. It is important to be precise in variable naming when doing crypto.